# How to make all elements isit on the same elevation in a row

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

As seen in the picture, I have a text field and button placed in the same row on two lines. I am trying to design it so that each element is positioned on the same y-cord in each row (basically have them sitting at the same elevation). Currently, the  LB and FT buttons and the Text that says "Inches" are sort of hovering a bit over the textfields, which is what I don't want.

this is the code for the screen:

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:juicefit/components/square_button.dart';

class MemberSignUpGoals extends StatefulWidget {
  static String id = "MemberSignUpGoals";

  @override
  _MemberSignUpGoals createState() => _MemberSignUpGoals();
}

class _MemberSignUpGoals extends State<MemberSignUpGoals> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Color(0xffE5DDDD),
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            textColor: Colors.white,
            onPressed: () {

            },
            child: Text('Next'),
          )
        ],
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff32416F),
        title: Text('Member Sign Up'),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 24.0, right: 24.0, bottom: 24.0),
              child: Center(
                child: Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                focusedBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black, width: 3.0)),
                                enabledBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black, width: 3.0)),
                                hintText: 'First Name',
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0),
                          child: SquareButton(
                            color:  Color(0xff32416F),
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            pressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                              });
                            },
                            butName: 'LB',
                            buttonwidth: 50.0,
                            height: 37.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          width: 50.0,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                    Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: TextField(
                            decoration: InputDecoration(
                                focusedBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black, width: 3.0)),
                                enabledBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
                                    borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                        color: Colors.black, width: 3.0)),
                                hintText: 'First Name',
                                hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.black,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0),
                          child: SquareButton(
                            color:  Color(0xff32416F),
                            textColor: Colors.white,
                            pressed: () {
                              setState(() {
                              });
                            },
                            butName: 'FT',
                            buttonwidth: 50.0,
                            height: 37.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Expanded(
                          flex: 1,
                          child: Padding(
                            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0),
                            child: TextField(
                              decoration: InputDecoration(
                                  focusedBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.black, width: 3.0)),
                                  enabledBorder: new UnderlineInputBorder(
                                      borderSide: new BorderSide(
                                          color: Colors.black, width: 3.0)),
                                  hintText: 'First Name',
                                  hintStyle: TextStyle(color: Colors.black)),
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left:10.0),
                          child: Text("inches"),
                        )
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

this is the code for the squarebutton:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SquareButton extends StatelessWidget{
  final color;
  final pressed;
  final textColor;
  final String butName;
  final buttonwidth;
  final height;
  SquareButton({@required this.color,@required this.pressed,@required this.butName,@required this.textColor, @required this.buttonwidth,this.height});
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context){
    return Padding(
      padding:EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical:10.0),
      child:Material(
        elevation: 5.0,
        color:color,
        child: Container(
          width: buttonwidth,
          height: height == null ? 45.0 : height ,
          child: MaterialButton(
              onPressed:pressed,
            child:Text(
              butName,
              style: TextStyle(
                color:textColor
              ),
            )
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }
```

}

Comment: using a Sizedbox and assign a fixed height same as the button ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set the `crossAxisAlignment` of both the rows to

```
crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
```

and remove the bottom padding of your `SquareButton`